# Changing meta data while app in review

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm about to upload an iOS App and want to be able to change certain metadata afterwards (e.g. when it is in the status: Pending Developer Release). I've found the following resources: [iTunes Connect App Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW1). In this document there are multiple tables with a column for Editable. But there is no information on which status this acutally is editable except for the first table. In this document: [Viewing and Changing Your App’s Status and Availability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW23), the several app status is listed and also with a column editable. So is it correct that after **In Review** nothing is editable anymore? I have another app which is live right now and i'm able to edit metadata which should not be possible considering the before mentioned document.

Answer (score 1):

While your app is in review you cannot change the metadata or screenshots. Wait until it is approved and change them afterwards. You can always reject your binary (even while it is in review), update the metadata and resubmit, but you'll have to wait in the review queue again.

Comment: If i change it after in review will there be another review? If not this makes somehow no sense ..

Comment: For the fields that are editable there is no additional review. Fields that require additional review will be locked down, and to change them you'll need to submit a new build.

Comment: If you change them afterwards, they will probably go live on your next update.

Comment: Are you certain about that? Seems odd that it is editable but will go live with the next update.